# In SharePoint 2007, how can I have one list displayed on two different sites/workspaces?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I have a site A.  I created two events(meetings) on the site, each one with its own workspace.  In one of the meetings, I added a list--a "Project Tasks" list, in particular--and I want to be able to display that list on the other event's workspace.  I also want to be able to synchronize the two, so that any items added to one list get added to the other.

Any ideas on how I can do that in SharePoint 2007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are saying that you have a top level site with two sub-sites which you are referring to as workspaces.  In one of them you have the Project Tasks list.  If my assumptions are correct...

I recommend that you use just one list and then use SharePoint Designer and the [Data Form Web Part](http://masteringsharepoint.com/blogs/beagle/archive/2008/08/13/DFWP1.aspx) to display the content in another site.

Comment: That's right.  The only catch is that I want to be able to show it in the same view--a Gantt chart.  It looks liek the Data Form Web 
Part will fit the job, though.  Thanks!